# Pythonic way to combine a join with CSV writerow

Tags: python, join, export-to-csv

I have two CSV rows which I would like to iterate over only once. Notice they combine two models, Inventory and Material. How could I combine the two tables into a single csv export?

Table:

```
[outcsv.writerow([getattr(curr, column.name) for column in Inventory.__mapper__.columns]) for curr in records]
```

Join:

```
[outcsv.writerow([getattr(curr.material, column.name) for column in Material.__mapper__.columns]) for curr in records]
```

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

Oh this was simple.

```
[outcsv.writerow([getattr(curr, column.name) for column in Inventory.__mapper__.columns] + [getattr(curr.material, column.name) for column in Material.__mapper__.columns]) for curr in records]
```